# Phoenix 1.3 (Elixir) Error: Myapp.Users.User.__struct__/0 is undefined, cannot expand struct Myapp.Users.User

Tags: data-structures, elixir, phoenix-framework

Trying to build an API using **Phoenix v1.3** following this tutorial: 
https://dreamconception.com/tech/phoenix-full-fledged-api-in-five-minutes 
(*made sure to follow each step to the letter*)

When I attempt to run  `mix ecto.setup`

I get the following error:
[image: error]

```
Compiling 17 files (.ex)

== Compilation error on file lib/myapp/users/users.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/myapp/users/users.ex:65: Myapp.Users.User.__struct__/0 is undefined, cannot expand struct Myapp.Users.User
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    lib/myapp/users/users.ex:65: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

The `lib/myapp/users/users.ex` is quite big: https://github.com/nelsonic/phoenix-api-example/blob/master/lib/myapp/users/users.ex#L65

Complete code on GitHub: https://github.com/nelsonic/phoenix-api-example

Any help debugging it would be *much* appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to have a module of `MyApp.Users.User`.

Comment: Shouldn't those files under `web/` be in `lib/` in Phoenix 1.3? I can see `defmodule Myapp.Users.User` in `web/models/coherence/user.ex`.

Comment: @Dogbert well spotted, I think `Coherence` is _assuming_ it's a V1.2 app...

Answer (score 3):

So there are a few things that I'm noticing:

1. You've named your context after your record. You should name your context after the idea the records are a part of. Something like `Authentication` or `Account`
2. Building off of #1, in a Phoenix 1.3 app where you have an `Account` context, you might have user records associated with that context. In that case you'd have Myapp.Account.Users defined in lib/myapp/account/users.ex. This is where your struct would come from.
3. I think how you've ended up here, is that the context is named the same as your records and that's causing some confusion. On line 9 of your `Users` context you're aliasing `Myapp.Users.User` but that module is never defined.